# TenantConnectionProvider cannot find a datasource when multiple data sources are enabled

Tags: spring, kotlin, datasource, multi-tenant, boot

I am creating a Spring Kotlin application that uses multi-tenancy. I want to add a second data source to my application.

The multi-tenancy works fine with a single data source using Spring Boot JPA autoconfiguration. I did not need to create any DatasourceConfiguration classes.

Since I want to add a second data source, I cannot rely on the autoconfiguration anymore, instead I have to create configuration classes for each data source as such:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerA",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryA",
    basePackages = ["com.myapp.repository.a"]
)
class DataSourceConfigA {
}
```

The multi-tenancy is enabled by a `TenantConnectionProvider` class as such:

```kotlin
@Component
class TenantConnectionProvider :
    MultiTenantConnectionProvider,
    HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var datasource: DataSource

    override fun getAnyConnection(): Connection = datasource.connection
   
    ...
}
```

Since I added the `DataSourceConfig` classes to configure my multiple data sources, the `datasource` in `TenantConnectionProvider` is not autowired anymore, and database queries using multi-tenancy fail.

I am getting the following error:

```
lateinit property dataSource has not been initialized
```

Why does disabling JPA autoconfig break datasource autowiring in my `TenantConfigProvider`?

How can I combine multi-tenancy and multiple data sources in my Spring Boot Kotlin application?

Answer (score 0):

Take a peak at the [MultiTenantConnectionProviderInitializor class](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/connections/internal/MultiTenantConnectionProviderInitiator.java#L48) that provides the `TenantConnectionProvider` to your application.

It searches for the `hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider` configuration value from `application.yml`. If it can find it, it checks whether the class is an instance of `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` at which point it returns that class.

In your code above, the configuration is a String (`com.myapp.config.TenantConnectionProvider`), and the initiator ultimately tries to instantiate the class with `implClass.newInstance()`, without autowiring any beans. The `datasource` is not initialized and any future connection will then fail.

In your datasource configuration class, you could overwrite the `hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider` property to use an instance of `TenantConnectionProvider` that uses injected beans, as such:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerA",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryA",
    basePackages = ["com.myapp.repository.a"]
)
class DataSourceConfigA {
    
    ...

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun tenantConnectionProvider(): MultiTenantConnectionProvider = TenantConnectionProvider()
    
    @Bean(name = ["entityManagerFactoryA"])
    @Primary
    fun postgresEntityManagerFactory(
        dataSource: DataSource,
        builder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.myapp.domain.a")
            // Overwrite hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider to use a class instance
            .properties(mapOf(Pair("hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider", tenantConnectionProvider())))
            .build()
    }
    
    ...

}
```

This will cause the initiator to use your own instance instead of trying to instantiate a class without autowired beans.